# Узнать границы контура

Tags: c++, c, opencv

Хочу узнать границы контура хаотичной кривой. Может быть как закрашенная фигура, так и пустая или текст любого размера. Надо узнать позицию контура. Ширину, высоту и позицию загогулины на кадре.

С помощью OpenCV через `findContours`, `boundingRect` и центр масс это делается, но не могу сообразить как.
Например, какие координаты самой левой, правой, верхней и нижней точек? Может, вообще по-другому это легче ищется?
[image: Возможна такая кривая.]

Comment: Не очень понятен Ваш вопрос. С одной стороны, пишите о `findContours()` (что как бы намекает на некоторую осведомлённость в тематике), но при этом, с другой, что-то Вас смущает: "...не могу сообразить как". В чём именно заключается вопрос? Как Вы пытались самостоятельно решить задачу? Лучше всего привести пример кода.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Предположим, имеем на входе такое изображение:

[image: исходное изображение]

Загружаем изображение в матрицу в оттенках серого:

```
cv::Mat src_mat = cv::imread("line.png", cv::IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);
```

Несмотря на то, что на картинке, в общем, мы видим лишь два цвета, на самом деле на пограничных пикселях между белым фоном и чёрной линией присутствуют промежуточные значения, варьирующиеся в диапазоне от 0 до 255.

Для поиска контуров чёрной линии такое разнообразие значений не требуется. Чётко разделить цвета на чёрный и белый поможет бинаризация:

```
cv::Mat bin_mat;
cv::threshold(src_mat, bin_mat, 127, 255, cv::THRESH_BINARY_INV);
```

что даст вот такое изображение, заключённое в `bin_mat`:

[image: бинаризованное изображение]

Флаг `cv::THRESH_BINARY_INV` вместо обычно применяемого `cv::THRESH_BINARY` выбран для того, чтобы была произведена т.н. обратная бинаризация, когда цвет каждого пикселя меняется на противоположный по простой формуле:

```
pixel_value = 255 - pixel_value
```

В OpenCV во многих функциях принято по умолчанию, что пиксели фона должны иметь значение `0`, а объекты - любые значения от `1` до `255` включительно (впрочем, негласно принято брать именно `255`). Так как в рассматриваемом случае линия является объектом интереса, то именно по этой причине в коде была выполнена обратная бинаризация.

Теперь можно осуществить поиск контура линии:

```
std::vector<std::vector<cv::Point> > contours;
cv::findContours(bin_mat, contours, cv::RETR_EXTERNAL, cv::CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
```

Если его нарисовать, то получится следующее изображение:

[image: контур линии]

Поиск контуров всегда возвращает замкнутые, опоясывающие исходное изображение фигуры даже в том случае, если толщина исходника в отдельных местах составляет не более одного пикселя.

Для получения позиции контура (за нулевую отметку всегда берётся верхняя левая точка матрицы) достаточно воспользоваться конструкцией, которая возвратит минимально описанный вокруг линии прямоугольник:

```
cv::Rect line_rect = cv::boundingRect(contours[0]);
```

Однако, если требуется ещё и центр, то проще использовать:

```
cv::RotatedRect rot_rect = cv::minAreaRect(contours[0]);

// Центр фигуры.
float center = rot_rect.center;

// Такой же прямоугольник, что и в предыдущем примере.
cv::Rect line_rect = rot_rect.boundingRect();
```

Теперь объект `line_rect` структуры `cv::Rect` содержит координаты прямоугольника, стороны которого лежат на самой левой (`line_rect.x`), правой (`line_rect.x + line_rect.width`), верхней (`line_rect.y`) и нижней (`line_rect.y + line_rect.height`) точках контура.